# Android java implement vertical step progress bar in widget

Tags: java, android, android-layout, widget, android-widget

[image]

I would like to implement a vertical step progress bar in the android widget.

The fields must not be entered by the user, the texts I already have are taken from http.

What concerns me is memory, widgets have limited memory.

I have an array of elements like this:

```java
JSONArray steps = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0; i < info.length(); i++){
     JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
     Boolean reached = steps.getJSONObject(i).getBoolean("reached");
     String message = steps.getJSONObject(i).getString("message");
     String data = steps.getJSONObject(i).getString("data");
     item.put("reached", reached);
     item.put("message", message);
     item.put("data", data);
     steps.put(item);
}
```

I was thinking of using a listview, but I don't know how to do vertical swipes from one row to another.

Or are there any library you recommend?

Can you give me a hand?